# Edit only specific lines when I find special character with awk

Tags: awk

I have this kind of file :

```
>AX-89948491-minus
CTAACACATTTAGTAGATT
>AX-89940152-plus
cgtcattcagggcaggtggggcaaaA
>AX-89922107-plus
TTATAACTTGTGTATGCTCTCAGGCT
```

When the lines start by ">" and include "minus" , I need to reverse (`rev`) and translate (`tr`) the next following lines. I should get :

```
>AX-89948491-minus
AATCTACTAAATGTGTTAG
>AX-89940152-plus
cgtcattcagggcaggtggggcaaaA
>AX-89922107-plus
TTATAACTTGTGTATGCTCTCAGGCT
```

I would like to go with awk. I tried that but it does not work..

```
awk '{if(NR%2==1~/"plus"/){print;getline;print} else if (NR%2==1~/"minus"/){system("echo "$0" | rev | tr ATCGatcg TAGCtagc")} else {print;getline;print}}' file
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you please explain more on substitution part once in your question, thank you.

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `gnu-awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk '
p {
   cmd = "rev <<< \047" $0 "\047 | tr ATCGatcg TAGCtagc"
   if ((cmd |& getline var) > 0)
      $0 = var
}
{
   p = /^>/ && /-minus/
} 1' file

>AX-89948491-minus
AATCTACTAAATGTGTTAG
>AX-89940152-plus
cgtcattcagggcaggtggggcaaaA
>AX-89922107-plus
TTATAACTTGTGTATGCTCTCAGGCT
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk is a tool to manipulate text, not a tool to sequence calls to other tools. The latter is what a shell is for. There are times when you need to call other tools from awk but not when it's simple text manipulation like reversing and translating characters in a string as you want to do.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box without spawning a subshell once per target input line to call other Unix tools (including the non-POSIX-defined `rev` which won't exist on some Unix boxes):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("ATCGatcg TAGCtagc",tmp)
    for (i=1; i<=length(tmp[1]); i++) {
        tr[substr(tmp[1],i,1)] = substr(tmp[2],i,1)
    }
}
f {
    out = ""
    for (i=1; i<=length($0); i++) {
        char = substr($0,i,1)
        out = (char in tr ? tr[char] : char) out
    }
    $0 = out
    f = 0
}
/^>.*minus/ { f=1 }
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>AX-89948491-minus
AATCTACTAAATGTGTTAG
>AX-89940152-plus
cgtcattcagggcaggtggggcaaaA
>AX-89922107-plus
TTATAACTTGTGTATGCTCTCAGGCT
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl, as it has builtin `reverse` and `tr` functions:

```sh
perl -lpe '
    if (/^>/) {$rev = /minus/; next}
    if ($rev) {$_ = reverse; tr/ATCGatcg/TAGCtagc/}
' file
```

```
>AX-89948491-minus
AATCTACTAAATGTGTTAG
>AX-89940152-plus
cgtcattcagggcaggtggggcaaaA
>AX-89922107-plus
TTATAACTTGTGTATGCTCTCAGGCT
```